# regex search and replace - notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am using following regex search and replace (notepad++)

```
show<sup>[1]</sup> references<sup>[13]</sup>
<sup><xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref$1">$1</xref></sup>
```

to find / replace below text

```
show<sup>[1]</sup> references<sup>[13]</sup>
show<sup><a ref-type="abc" rid="ref[1]">[1]</a></sup> references<sup><a ref-type="bibr" rid="ref[13]">[13]</a></sup>
```

But my replacement should be like below

```
show<sup><a ref-type="abc" rid="ref1">[1]</a></sup> references<sup><a ref-type="bibr" rid="ref13">[13]</a></sup>
```

**without square brackets**

Pl help me

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Could you show us some of your attempts?

Comment: your question is quite confusing..show use your input and your required output at the end of your question without regex

Comment: input: show<sup>[1]</sup> references<sup>[13]</sup>

Comment: output: show<sup><a ref-type="abc" rid="ref1">[1]</a></sup> references<sup><a ref-type="bibr" rid="ref13">[13]</a></sup>

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`<sup>\[(\d+)\]</sup>(.*)<sup>\[(\d+)\]</sup>`

with

`<sup><a ref-type="abc" rid="ref\1">\[\1\]</a></sup>\2<sup><a ref-type="bibr" rid="ref\3">\[\3\]</a></sup>`